Hyphenation at the end of the line
I have an issue with hyphenation. Here is the code

\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{amsbook}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{txfonts}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{mathdots}
\usepackage{epigraph}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{verbatim,enumitem}
\usepackage[british]{babel}


\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition}
\newtheorem{remark}[theorem]{Remark}
\newtheorem{example}[theorem]{Example}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd\@thm
{\let\thm@indent\indent}{\let\thm@indent\noindent}%
{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    
    \title{Result}


aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa existence


\end{document}

The word existence is broken as ex-istence, which I believe is not correct.
I used all the solutions here but none seems to work.
Thank you.

What makes you think this is incorrect? The Oxford English dictionary splits into syllables as ex-ist-ence both for British and American English. By the way, I recommend not using txfonts: the spacings, particularly in math, are disputable.

Thank you @egreg, I will remove txtfonts. I thought it is incorrect because the splitting should at least respect the syllables and "ex" is not a syllable.  Thank you for bringing this to my attention. I

Your current example doesn't hyphenate existence as you said.
And even if it did, the hyphenation would be correct.
Anyway, here is a following MWE with what you are asking
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{amsbook}

\usepackage{txfonts}
\usepackage[british]{babel}

\begin{document}
    
    \title{Result}
    
    
    aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaa existence
    
    
    aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaa exis\-tence
    
    
\end{document}

Bear in mind that in your example you are using aaaaa....aaa as a single word, and as a effect of this, there is not a lot of glue to stretch.

The british hyphenation patterns give the hyphenation points as ex-ist-ence. Why do you think that incorrect?
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage[british]{babel}

\showhyphens{existence}

\begin{document}

\end{document}

If you do not like the break points generated by the default patterns you can specify a hyphenation exception:
Adding
\hyphenation{exist-ence}

would just allow hyphenation after the t:
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage[british]{babel}
\hyphenation{exist-ence}

\showhyphens{existence}

\begin{document}

\end{document}

